# Change subtitles on Apple TV?

Tags: appletv

How can I change the subtitle language on an Apple TV?

I’m using the iPhone *Remote* app as the remote.

The Apple TV is 3rd gen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to do a “long press” gesture on the area representing the touch surface.

Sometimes this doesn’t work though, which I consider a bug. Rebooting the Apple TV might help in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Slide down with one of your fingers inside the area representing the touch surface in the Remote app on your iPhone and a menu including Info, Subtitles, etc. should appear at the top of the video playing on the Apple TV.

Move to Subtitles using the touch surface in the app again and move onto and tap on any of the subtitle options that would appear. If the menu at the top of the video does not disappear after choosing a subtitle, tap on the MENU button in the app so that the menu at the top of the video disappears.

Comment: That doesn’t work I’m afraid. Perhaps that works for the 4th Gen and newer?